# Exchange BSON data with asp page

Tags: .net, asp.net, json, bson

Good day.

What am I trying to do is to exchange serialized data between client application and asp.net page.

I use the following classes for exchange:

```
public class Send
{
    public Guid guidField;
    public string stringField1;
    public string stringField2;
    public byte[] data;
}
```

and

```
public class Receive
{
    public Guid guidField;
    public byte[] data;
}
```

On client side I use the following code to make a request:

```
public Receive Exchange(Send send)
{
    Receive receive = new Receive();
    string address = "example.org";

    HttpWebRequest client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
    client.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    client.Timeout = 90000;
    client.Method = "POST";
    client.UserAgent = "AgentMe";
    try
    {
        Stream stream = client.GetRequestStream(); 
        PackSend(stream, send);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();

        var response = client.GetResponse();
        Stream outputStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        UnpackReceive(outputStream, out receive);
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {  }
    return receive;
}
```

On server side I do it similarly but in the opposite direction:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream inputStream = Request.InputStream;
    Send send;
    UnpackSend(inputStream, out send);

    // here goes some useful work
    Receive receive = Process(send);

    Response.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    Stream stream = Response.OutputStream;

    PackReceive(stream, sent);
    Response.End();
}
```

For packing and unpacking data I use Newtonsoft.Json :

```
static void PackSend(Stream stream, Send message)
{
    BsonWriter writer = new BsonWriter(stream);
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    serializer.Serialize(writer, message);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}

void UnpackSend(Stream stream, out Send message)
{
    BsonReader reader = new BsonReader(stream);
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    message = serializer.Deserialize<Send>(reader);
}
```

The code for PackReceive/UnpackReceive is analogous.

When I use `ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` I'm able to do exchange but if only `public byte[] data` field size doesn't exceed ~1200 bytes. If size is larger I get Internal Server error 500 doing request.

Using `ContentType = "text/xml"`; any size of "public byte[] data" field is handled properly on server side. Useful work is done but when server tries to write into response stream I guess error occurs and automagicly request is repeated so client application is stuck, flooding server with multiple similar requests without throwing any error.
`ContentType = "application/octet-stream"` - shows the same behavior as "text/xml".

Can anyone suggest a proper `ContentType` string or give an advice how to proper handle this situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is your 500 error message the generic IIS one and not the ASP.Net one? If so that probably means that the data isn't even getting to ASP.Net and that IIS is choking on it. My first guess is that you're running into an upload limit. [Here's a way to increase this in IIS 6](http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/File_Upload_limits.asp). Once IIS is set you will also have to [change the value for ASP.Net](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx). As for your other errors, you should really look into trapping them. The .Net framework does a pretty good job of explaining what goes wrong.